# Ad-hoc type inference from function parameter?

Tags: typescript, callback, type-inference, arrow-functions

My TypeScript knowledge is limited but I'm currently working on a library port and the original is written in TypeScript.

I'm looking at this pit of code which defines an arrow function (as a callback in the bigger context):

```
({
        postgres_changes: serverPostgresFilters,
      }: {
        postgres_changes: {
          id: string
          event: string
          schema?: string
          table?: string
          filter?: string
        }[]
      }) => { if (serverPostgresFilters === undefined) { /* do something */ } }
```

Now I'm not sure what to make of this. The parameter going into the callback is just some payload string, so I guess it's TypeScript way of ad-hoc deserialization of the string to an object that contains the property `postgres_changes`, while the whole (anonymous) object has a type that contains the property `postgres_changes` which itself contains the properties `id`, `event`, `schema`, etc...).

If I'm not mistaken so far this would mean that `serverPostgresFilters` is a type, but I can't see where it's coming from as **it is declared nowhere**. How does this work? Is it auto-inferred as well from the information provided by the anonymous object declaration in the parameter list? I have never seen a type being checked like `serverPostgresFilters === undefined` so I might be mistaken.

Comment: It's not a type. It's the value of the property `postgres_changes`.

Comment: Ehh wait, that's not it, this syntax is renaming the property `postgres_changes` during the destructuring of the function parameter to `serverPostgresFilters` - this bit of code is not pretty

Comment: @geoffrey I didn't write it lol. But it's at least hard to understand. But then it's essentially what I thought it is.